# Hangman Game letters reset each time the button is pressed

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, if-statement

So I've been creating a hangman game and been having problems with each time a user guesses a correct letter again, the previous correct letter/letters gets removed.??

I tried a lot of if elses to hold each index of the letter and append if its correct but that did not work. So in general let's say a user got their first letter correct which was A. This is what happens..

XXXAXXAX

But the Second letter they get correct, lets say B this happens...

XBXXXXXX

they are supposed to bring A along to the next iteration and so onn.

can anyone see what's the problem? Here's my code below..

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var allWords = [String]()
    var usedLetters = [String]()
    var startWords = [String]()
    var promptWord = String()
    var randomWord = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        EnterGuess()
        fileWork()
        print(randomWord)
        
        title = "GUESS A Letter: ?????????)"
    }
    
    func fileWork() {
        
        if let startWordsURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "start", withExtension: "txt") {
            if let startWords = try? String(contentsOf: startWordsURL) {
                allWords = startWords.components(separatedBy: "\n")
                let wordssss = startWords.randomElement()
                
                randomWord =  allWords.randomElement()!
            }
        }
    }
    
    func EnterGuess() {
        
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Guess a letter", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addTextField()
        var submitGuess = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default) {_ in
            
            guard var answer = ac.textFields?[0].text else {return }
            answer
            
            self.submit(answer)
            self.EnterGuess()
            
        }
        ac.addAction(submitGuess)
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
    
    func submit(_ answer: String) {
        
        let guessedLetter = answer
        
        let wordArray = randomWord.map(String.init)
        var hidden = Array(repeating: "x", count: randomWord.count)
        
        for index in hidden.indices {
            if wordArray[index] == answer {
                hidden[index] = wordArray[index]
            }
        }
        
        print(hidden.joined())
        //   print(wordArray)
        title = String(describing: hidden.joined())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are "re-setting" the hidden string with each letter guess.

Instead, you want to create a class-level var:

```
var hidden = [String]()
```

and "re-set" it to "xxxxxx..." when you **start** a new game.

Then, with each guess, you'll be *keeping* the old letters and *replacing* new letters.

Suppose the game word is EASY:

- hidden is "xxxx"
- guessed letter is "A"

  - hidden goes from "xxxx" to "xAxx"
- guessed letter is "Y"

  - hidden goes from "xAxx" to "xAxY"
- guessed letter is "E"

  - hidden goes from "xAxY" to "EAxY"

and so on.

Here's a quick example you can run:

```
class HangmanViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    var allWords: [String] = [
        "easy",
        "birthday",
        "laboratory",
        "hangman",
        "iphone",
        "requirements",
        "gaming",
    ]

    var usedLetters = [String]()
    var startWords = [String]()
    var promptWord = String()
    var randomWord = ""
    
    var hidden = [String]()
    
    let tf = UITextField()
    let progressLabel = UILabel()
    let usedLabel = UILabel()
    let newGameButton = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tf.textAlignment = .center
        tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect

        tf.textAlignment = .center
        tf.font = .monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 24.0, weight: .light)

        tf.delegate = self
        
        progressLabel.textAlignment = .center
        progressLabel.font = .monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 24.0, weight: .light)
        progressLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        usedLabel.textAlignment = .center
        usedLabel.font = .monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .light)
        usedLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        
        newGameButton.setTitle("New Game", for: [])
        newGameButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        newGameButton.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        newGameButton.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        newGameButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        newGameButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        newGameButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        
        [tf, progressLabel, usedLabel, newGameButton].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            tf.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),
            tf.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 80.0),
            tf.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
            progressLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            progressLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tf.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            progressLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),

            usedLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            usedLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: progressLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            usedLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),

            newGameButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            newGameButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: usedLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            newGameButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),

        ])
        
        newGameButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(newGameTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        newGame()

    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        // upper-case the entered letter
        let s = string.uppercased()
        
        // we don't want to process if a string was pasted into the field
        if s.count != 1 {
            return false
        }
        
        // only allow A - Z
        if s.rangeOfCharacter(from: .uppercaseLetters) == nil {
            return false
        }
        
        // replace the current text
        textField.text = s
        
        // process the entered letter
        submit(s)
        
        // don't let the textfield process the string
        return false
    }

    func newGame() {

        // cycle the array of game words
        allWords.append(allWords.removeFirst())
        
        // safely unwrap
        guard let w = allWords.first else {
            fatalError("Bad setup")
        }
        
        // upper-case the word
        randomWord = w.uppercased()
        
        // set hidden string to "####..."
        hidden = Array(repeating: "#", count: randomWord.count)
        
        // clear used letters
        usedLetters = []
        
        // update the game progress label
        progressLabel.text = String(hidden.joined())
        progressLabel.textColor = .black

        // update used letters label
        usedLabel.text = " "

        // hide the new game button
        newGameButton.isHidden = true
        
        // re-enable text field
        tf.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        // for development
        print("New Game Word is:", randomWord)
        
    }
    
    func submit(_ answer: String) {
        
        if usedLetters.contains(answer) {
            return
        }
        usedLetters.append(answer)
        usedLabel.text = usedLetters.joined()
        
        let wordArray = randomWord.map(String.init)
        
        for index in hidden.indices {
            if wordArray[index] == answer {
                hidden[index] = wordArray[index]
            }
        }
        
        progressLabel.text = hidden.joined()
        
        if hidden == wordArray {
            progressLabel.textColor = .red
            
            // clear and disable text field
            tf.text = ""
            tf.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            
            // dismiss keyboard
            view.endEditing(true)
            
            // show the new game button
            newGameButton.isHidden = false
        }

    }
    
    @objc func newGameTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        newGame()
    }
    
}
```

It will look about like this (the cyan label will show the used letters). I'll type `T, R, Y, S, M, E, A`:

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Comment: Wow thanks man this made it worked I've been stuck on this for a week now lol!

Comment: @Karonbell It's great that you got the help you needed, but if you want to be a good citizen of Stack Overflow, abandon this trick of asking the same question three times in a row.

Comment: @Karonbell Another trick to being a good citizen of Stack Overflow; if an answer is what you needed, _accept_ that answer (checkmark). Otherwise you're just leeching, as it's called.